# C# MVC GetAssemblyDirectory() not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am currently working on a C# dot net web application and I'm almost new to it, I need to send an email, the emails templates are stored in this directory:

```
 C://rootToProject//EmailTemplates
```

I tried to render the email template with the help of the following code:

```
  string path = Path.Combine(GetAssemblyDirectory(),
         string.Format("EmailTemplates\\{0}.cshtml", Model.TemplateName));
```

This code is trying to render the template from this folder:

```
      C://rootToProject//bin/EmailTemplates
```

and obviously it fails,

Question is this : do I have to use another command to refer to the project root or do I have to edit config file so that GetAssemblyDirectory refers

```
   C://rootToProject//bin/EmailTemplates
```

Comment: have you tried `..\\EmailTemplates\\{0}.cshtml` as your second `.Combine()` parameter? OR you can use `DirectoryInfo.GetParent(GetAssemblyDirectory())`. Or, as @Tallmaris says, `Server.MapPath()`.

Comment: You are looking for `Server.MapPath("~/EmailTemplates/")` that will give you the path on the server relative the the website root.

Comment: Use `ControllerContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/EmailTemplates/")` or simply `HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/EmailTemplates")` within your controller class